# How to create buttons with irregular background in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, imagebutton

I would like to create a fancy header that includes some buttons with irregular background as following:

[image]

In above example, there are 5 buttons(more exactly, clickable area). Each of them has a irregular background and they fit in together. I guess each background image of buttons is split from original photo of menu bar. Each button here in fact is a complex layout. But how they can merge buttons in the way background fit perfectly together?  What techniques to make this?
Thank you very much for any answer.

Answer (score 2):

Just create buttons with background images that mesh together and then place the buttons next to each other with no gap in between.

Comment: Thanks Aelexe. Could you show me more details? For now, I just set value of layout_marginleft and layout_marginright of each clickable area to negative and fine-tune these values till they fit together, in a specific screen type, it works. But it's not right in other screen type (different sizes) in almost case.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Linear layout (with horizontal orientation) for that having weight sum=100 and then divide this weight among all five buttons equally. I think that would work in your case.

Comment: Thanks Rohit. Each background will be in fact a rectangle, so it still occupy transparent space. How to remove these transparent space when we merge buttons?

Comment: what kind of transparent space you are getting? can you be more specific?

Comment: Transparent space is the empty area in png image. In this case, each clickable area has a background that is png image ( with non-rectangular figure), and transparent space is compensatory part of rectangular surrounding png image.

Comment: Well the above images you used as an example are perfect rectangles with no transparency.

Answer (score 0):

Create a layout of Button separately
add your buttons in that layout 
add that Layout in your Main layout in which you want to Use those Buttons layout 
with `<include />` tag